# Merge (concatenate) multiple YouTube videos into one?

Tags: youtube

I want to merge (concatenate) a couple of public YouTube videos into a single one and re-upload this merged video onto my account unlisted to not invoke any copyright issues.

Anyone knows of a way that doesn't involve downloading the videos first?